# Facebook Javascript SDK - Cordova 2.5 - iOS not returning userId in acc

Tags: android, ios, cordova, facebook-javascript-sdk

i'm developing my first Facebook application, using Phonegap 2.5 and the Phonegap Facbook Connector Plugin.

On Android all works well, the code below displays the response and the user id is included in the response.

On iOS the exact same code works as well, an authtoken is returned, but the userId is empty in the result.

Do you have any idea what the problem might is?

Thanks for your help!

```
        FB.init({
                appId : "xxxx",
                nativeInterface : CDV.FB,
                useCachedDialogs : false
            });
    //Some code later, Init is already called
        FB.login(function(response) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
                            //response.authResponse.userId is empty on iOS, not on Android
        }, {
            scope : "email"
        });
```

Comment: Alert your access token once because sometimes some extra characters like #/ get added at the end of it.

Comment: I already solved the problem by calling the /me url at the facebook api. But thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already solved the problem by calling the /me url at the facebook api. But thanks!